# How to map data from two flowfiles using apache-nifi

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I have two apache-nifi flows. One taken from database and other coming from flowfile.

Taken from `QueryDatabaseTableRecord` processor. :

```
lat,long,location
232,3454,colombo
454,8834,kandy
438,94,galle
```

In my flowfile I have `lat` and `long` columns. What I want is compare `lat`, and `long` coming from two flows and if its match, add a new column to flowfile as `location`

The problem I am having is that(to use `ExecuteScript`), how to get values from both flows as they have identical names?

Or is there a way to use another processor to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try LookupRecord with a DatabaseRecordLookupService instead of QueryDatabaseTableRecord. You should specify user-defined properties `lat` to `/lat` and `long` to `/long` and a `Result RecordPath` of `/location`. If the lat/long of the flow file match the lat/long of a database row, it should return the value of `location`.